# constrained optimization including sum of two upper incomplete gamma function in both fitness function and constraint

Tags: optimization, gamma-function, nonlinear-optimization

i'm trying to solve this constrained optimization problem
the constraint is  $$\zeta=\frac {\Gamma \left(M,\frac {\lambda}{\left |\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i*h_{ei} \right|^2 + \sum_{i=1}^N\left |w_i \right|^2} \right)}{\Gamma(M)}*\beta +\frac {\Gamma \left(M,\frac {\lambda}{\sum_{i=1}^N \left |w_i \right|^2} \right)}{\Gamma(M)}*(1-\beta)$$
and the fitness function is
$$P_d=\frac {\Gamma \left(M,\frac {\lambda}{\left |\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i*h_{pi} \right|^2+\left |\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i*h_{ei} \right|^2 + \sum_{i=1}^N\left |w_i \right|^2} \right)}{\Gamma(M)}*\alpha +\frac {\Gamma \left(M,\frac {\lambda}{\left |\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i*h_{pi} \right|^2 + \sum_{i=1}^N\left |w_i \right|^2} \right)}{\Gamma(M)}*(1-\alpha)$$
where $\Gamma(M,...)$ is upper incomplete gamma function. it is notable that $h_{pi}$ and $w_i$ are complex variables
in the above equations $\zeta$, $M$, $N$, $\beta$, $\alpha$, $\lambda$, $h_{pi}$ for(i=1,...,N) and $h_{ei}$ for(i=1,...,N) are known.
the parameters of our optimization problem are $\lambda$ and $w_i$ for (i=1,...,N) and the fitness function is $P_d$
this problem is from my telecommunication model
pleas guide me to solve this constrained optimization problem

Comment: Do you have any reason whatsoever to believe this is convex? (You tagged it as such.)

Comment: No, I said maybe. I wanted to be certain. thanks

Comment: If you have to guess than 99.99% the answer is no. Convexity tends to be obvious---at least when it is practical to exploit.